# c++ WINAPI How are BI_RGB 32 bit pixels stored?

Tags: java, c++, windows, bitmap, java-native-interface

I'm sending a bitmap from C++ to Java over JNI when i send a 24 bit bitmap the code works nicely but switching over to 32 bit displays the pixels not 100% correctly.

The bitmap header info contains:

```
BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;//24 works
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
```

I calculate the stride as following:

```
((width * bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount + 31) / 32) * 4
```

Then on the Java side I do

```
final byte[] bytes = getJNIImageBytes();
final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
image.setData(Raster.createInterleavedRaster(new DataBufferByte(bytes, bytes.length), size.width,
                size.height, ((size.width * 32 + 31) / 32) * 4, 4, new int[]{2, 1, 0, 3}, null));//2,1,0,3 = BGRA to RGBA
```

pixels like `RGB[217, 20, 95]` show correctly but pixels expected to be `RGB[113, 167, 199]` show as `RGB[240, 240, 240]`

Below is an image to explain my problem better:

[image: problem]

Comment: `biBitCount==32` - "Each DWORD in the bitmap array represents the relative intensities of blue, green, and red for a pixel. The value for blue is in the least significant 8 bits, followed by 8 bits each for green and red. The high byte in each DWORD is not used. " source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have read that article before, I just don't seem to comprehend where the alpha channel comes into play. Am I doing it right but just need to do some with `bmiColors` in the bitmap header?

Comment: I don't think there is an alpha channel in that format just an expanded RGB into 4 bytes.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if i use 24 or 32 bit images because the transparency is not captured?